# Openstack Compute API Update Server Tags

Tags: python, django, openstack, openstack-horizon, openstacksdk

I am using Django Rest API on open stack version 2.1 Unable to update Server Tags it is giving response text:'{"itemNotFound": {"code": 404, "message": "The resource could not be found."}}'
the code explanation is there is an array of object contains multiple server objects with updated tags within a loop it will request and append responses in an array for front-end

```
@classmethod
    def update_tags(self, params):
        check(self, params)
        responses = []
        try:

            headers = {
                "X-Auth-Token": params.headers['x-auth-token'],
                "Content-type": 'application/json'
            }

            for server in params.data['payload']:
                replace_tags = {"tags": server["tags"]}
                response=requests.put(os.environ.get('PROTOCOL')+'://'+os.environ.get('OPENSTACK_HOST')+':'+os.environ.get('COMPUTE_PORT')+'/v2.1/servers/' +server['id']+'/tags', data=json.dumps(replace_tags), headers=headers, verify=False)
                responses.append(response)
            return responses
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

parameters which are being passed from check method which is written below

```
def check(self, params):

    self.connection = get_openstack_conn(params)
```

the get_openstack_conn method

```
def get_openstack_conn(params):
    token = params.META.get("HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN")
    scope = params.META.get("HTTP_X_SCOPE")
    organization = params.META.get("HTTP_X_ORG")
    print("environment variables")
    print("PROTOCOL = ",os.environ.get('PROTOCOL'))
    print("OPENSTACK_HOST = ",os.environ.get('OPENSTACK_HOST'))
    print("KEY_STONE_PORT = ",os.environ.get('KEY_STONE_PORT'))
    if(scope == 'projectScope'):
        connector = openstack.connect(auth_url=os.environ.get('PROTOCOL')+'://'+os.environ.get('OPENSTACK_HOST') +
                                      ':'+os.environ.get('KEY_STONE_PORT')+'/v3', verify=False, auth_type="token", token=token, project_id=organization)
    elif(scope == 'domainScope'):
        connector = openstack.connect(auth_url=os.environ.get('PROTOCOL')+'://'+os.environ.get('OPENSTACK_HOST') +
                                      ':'+os.environ.get('KEY_STONE_PORT')+'/v3', verify=False, auth_type="token", token=token, domain_id=organization)

    return connector
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing? Can you show us your actual code?

Comment: thanks for your response, I have updated my question if there is something more to add then tell me please.

Comment: "The resource could not be found" simply means that there is no such server. Have you checked whether the `requests.put` URLs are correct? Additionally, I would do what the program does on the command line, e.g. use the URL and other parameters passed to `requests.put` and submit the request manually with `curl`.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by OpenStack 2.1? OpenStack releases are not numbered. Nova 2 would be Bexar, the release from 2011.